# Unable to install picamera2 on Rasbperry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, picamera

I'm trying to run a python script in my Rasbperry pi that imports the package picamera2. Specifically using `from picamera2 import Picamera2,Preview`

However, I'm getting this error:
`ImportError: No module named 'picamera2'`

Struggling to get it installed. Why can't this package be found?

I've tried to install the package by doing an update and installing the package (as indicated in https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install -y python3-picamera2
```

But running the last line returns the error: `Unable to locate package python3-picamera2`

I've also tried `pip install picamera2` but that returns `No matching distribution found for picamera2`

Info:

- Rasbperry pi 3 Model B
- OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I resolved running: `/usr/bin/python3 ./your_script.py` instead of `python ./your_script.py`.

The problem was that my default python was /home/pi/miniconda3/bin/python but the command `sudo apt install -y python3-picamera2` installs the package for /usr/bin/python3. This at least what I understood.